# Multiple hypothesis testing: lower bound for sample complexity of finding the different one

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, decision-theory

We have $m$ distributions $D_1,\dots,D_m$. We know that $m-1$ of them are $\mathcal{N}(\epsilon,\sigma^2)$ ($\epsilon>0$) and one of them is $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, but we don't know which one is. We can obtain i.i.d. samples $X_i\sim(D_1,\dots,D_m)$, where $X_i\in \mathbb{R}^m$. If we get $n$ such samples and we try to identify $j$ such that $D_j$ is $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, what is the lower bound of the probability that we find a wrong $j$? This lower bound should be independent of the estimation method (there is one for the classical binary hypothesis testing [https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~jrb/resources/Minimax_Lower_Bound_Notes.pdf](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Ejrb/resources/Minimax_Lower_Bound_Notes.pdf)). Thank you!